# Avoiding concurrency in Spring Batch jobs in a cluster environment

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, jboss

I want to ensure that a Spring job is not started a second time while it still runs. This would be trivial in a single JVM environment.

However, how can I achieve this in a cluster environment (more specifically, in JBoss 5.1 - I know a bit antiquated; if solutions exist for later versions, I'd be interested in those as well).

So, it should be kind of a Singleton pattern across all cluster nodes.

I am considering using database locks or a message queue. Is there a simpler / better performing solution?

Comment: When u mention spring jobs meaning what kind of jobs? are these spring batch jobs?

Comment: Yes, spring batch jobs.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to synchronize threads that doesn't know nothing each other, so the easiest way is to share some information on a common place. Valid alternatives are:

- A shared database
- A shared file
- An external web service holding the status of the batch process

If you prefer to use a shared database try to use a database like [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/faq) to improve your performance. It is an in memory database with persistence on disk, so accessing the status of the batch process should be enough fast.

Comment: Thank you very much - that confirms my suspicion that there is no inherent cluster-specific synchronization mechanism. And thanks for pointing out Redis - I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is too late but for future lookups: spring batch uses a jpa repository to synchronize jobs, so you can avoid concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Job Listener and in the before step and use [JobExecutionDao](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JobExecutionDao.html#findJobExecutions%28org.springframework.batch.core.JobInstance%29) in it to find all [JobExecutions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecution.html). If there are more than one running - throw an exception and exit the job.